# I'm trying to iterate through two arrays in Java, while also checking to see if the values are equal

Tags: java, arrays, string-comparison

I am trying to iterate through many arrays, two at a time. They contain upwards of ten-thousand entries each, including the source. In which I am trying to assign each word to either a noun, verb, adjective, or adverb.

I can't seem to figure a way to compare two arrays without writing an if else statement thousands of times.

I searched on Google and SO for similar issues. I couldn't find anything to move me forward.

```
package wcs;

import dictionaryReader.dicReader;
import sourceReader.sourceReader;

public class Assigner {
    private static String source[], snArray[], svArray[], sadvArray[], sadjArray[];
    private static String nArray[], vArray[], advArray[], adjArray[];
    private static boolean finished = false;

public static void sourceAssign() {
    sourceReader srcRead = new sourceReader();
    //dicReader dic = new dicReader();
    String[] nArray = dicReader.getnArray(), vArray = dicReader.getvArray(), advArray = dicReader.getAdvArray(),
            adjArray = dicReader.getAdjArray();

    String source[] = srcRead.getSource();

    // Noun Store
    for (int i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
        if (source[i] == dicReader.getnArray()[i]) {
            source[i] = dicReader.getnArray()[i];               
        }else{

        }
    }
    // Verb Store

    // Adverb Store

    // Adjective Store
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to do.What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If the order doesn't matter (and it seems like it doesn't), you can use `ArrayList<String>` instead of arrays. Then you'll be able to use `.contains()`, iterate through the lists with iterators, etc.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'm trying to compare one value(entry) in each array and if they are equal assign the source value to a new part of speech array.(noun, verb, adj, adv Array)

Comment: So you're trying to only assign `noun, verb, adj` if a value is in both lists?

Comment: Oh yeahhhhhh. I totally forgot about arraylists. Gotta go learn them again :O

Comment: Yes @SamOrozco.

Comment: Gotcha. I have a solution for you.

Comment: Hey, before this topic is closed. Any tips on my coding style(readability / formatting)(? Thanks in advance :O
And what would that be? @SamOrozco

Comment: @LiveBacteria I am writing it up now. Basically leveraging the `ArrayList.retainAll()` function.

Comment: @LiveBacteria Some tips would be using better variable names, and code styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this is a simpler way to get a list of items that are in both `Lists`

```
// construct a list of item for first list
        List<String> firstList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[0])); // add items
        //this function will only keep items in `firstList` if the value is in both lists
        firstList.retainAll(Arrays.asList(new String[0]));

        // iterate to do your work
        for(String val:firstList) {

        }
```

Comment: Wow, yeah that makes it so much easier. Thank you much man. so the 'val:firstList' is an iterator?

Comment: Yes that will iterate you’re entire first list